# How to inject a component selector into angular html

Tags: html, angular, components, inject

I have a list of components that I want to add to a dashboard.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTzB9.png)

I want to inject it to the html like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s00HZ.png)

the problem is I get a simple string in place of the component :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMrvb.png)

does anyone have an idea on why and how to fix it?

Comment: I think you need to use Angular Custom Elements here. Read more on those - https://angular.io/guide/elements

Comment: I don't need to creat new components I already have them I just need to inject them in the main component.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve can be done by dynamic component loading. Follow this guide https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader